# Why is this code faster?

Tags: c++, optimization

This problem is driving me insane. The code on the top executes in around 0.3s on my computer while the code on the bottom executes in around 2.7s. However, I've tried to adjust the second code to be as similar to the first code as I possibly can but it just always seems to be slower. Can anyone tell me why the first code executes so much faster than the second one?

**FASTER CODE**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>
#define ls(x) (x & (-x))
using namespace std;
int tc, n;
set<long long> s;
long long p, a[35];
int main () {
    freopen("mini3b.in","r",stdin);
    scanf("%d", &tc);
    while (tc--) {
        s.clear();
        scanf("%lld%d", &p, &n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) scanf("%lld", &a[i]);
        int h = n/2;
        for (int i = 0; i < (1<<h); ++i) {
            long long sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j) if (i&(1<<j)) sum += a[j];
            s.insert(sum);
        }
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; (i < (1<<(n-h))) && !found; ++i) {
            long long sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n-h; ++j) if (i&(1<<j)) sum += a[h+j];
            if (s.find(p-sum) != s.end()) found = true;
        }
        printf(found? "YES\n":"NO\n");
    }
}
```

**SLOWER CODE**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
long long n, bars[35];
int t, p;
set<long long> s;
int main(){
    freopen("mini3b.in","r", stdin);
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--){
        s.clear();
        scanf("%lld%d", &n, &p);
        for (int i=0;i<p;++i) scanf("%lld", &bars[i]);
        int limit=p/2;
        for (int i=0;i<(1<<limit);++i){
            long long sum=0;
            for (int j=0;j<limit;++j) if (i&(1<<j)) sum+=bars[j];
            s.insert(sum);
        }
        bool found=false;
        for (int i=0;i<(1<<(n-limit))&&!found;++i){
            long long sum=0;
            for (int j=0;j<p-limit;++j) if (i&(1<<j)) sum+=bars[limit+j];
            if (s.find(n-sum) != s.end()) 
                found=true;
        }
        printf(found?"YES\n":"NO\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you compare release versions.

Comment: The first one has a preprocessor macro but I don't see it being used anywhere...

Comment: Both were executed on the same computer one after the other if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I can't seem to find any difference between the programs at a quick glance. Why not compare the assembler code for both programs?

Comment: @cortex, do you build them with the same settings?

Comment: How about using a profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 4th for-loop you have

```
for (int i = 0; (i < (1<<(n-h))) && !found; ++i) { // fast one
                          ^
```

against

```
for (int i=0;i<(1<<(n-limit))&&!found;++i){ // slow one
                    ^
```

Note that the 'n' in the fast-code is the 'p' in the slow-code. So you should have

```
for (int i=0;i<(1<<(p-limit))&&!found;++i){ // slow one
                    ^
```

Comment: Another reason to use longer variable names (and not using THE SAME name different ways around). I just found the same thing, but I was a little bit slower...

Comment: I would never have found that :/ Thanks